# javascript Running a function under another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 functions, with the third function under the first that I want to run in the second.

```
function first () {
    function third () {
    }
}

function second () {
    third ();
}
```

How can I make second run third correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: What is happening incorrectly?

Comment: @james, third is a private method within first and second cannot call it

Comment: I just like to know what is happening. :) Did they run it and get an error?

Comment: Yes, you'll likely get a "not defined" error. There is no way that this will work.

Comment: @ ates, it wont work as is, but you can either make it public or make a public method that calls the private method.  There are also multiple ways to approach either solution

Comment: I meant: "there is no way this will work, the way it is". But, see my answer below, for a hack that allows you to tap into to third() function without any changes to the above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on how you want to setup the first function and how you want to access it.  Basically the third method is private to first.  You'll need a public method on first to call third.  That method would be called by second.

There are various ways to do this, one that comes to mind is this...

Edit: I named the parameters a little better, that way its not "param" over and over.

```
function first()
{
    // define first's private
    var third = function(third_param)
    {
        alert(third_param);
    }

    // define first's public that calls the private
    this.callThird = function (call_third_param)
    {
        third(call_third_param);
    }

}

function second ()
{
    // get an instance of first
    var temp = new first();

    // call the public method on it
    temp.callThird('argument');
}
```

If you don't care about third being private, you can do

```
function first() { }

// public method
first.prototype.third = function(third_param)
{
    alert(third_param);
}


function second ()
{
    // get an instance of first
    var temp = new first();

    // call the public method on it
    temp.third('argument');
}
```

or, this way, this is also not using privates

```
function first()
{
    // the "this", makes it public
    this.third = function(third_param)
    {
        alert(third_param);
    }

}

function second ()
{
    // get an instance of first
    var temp = new first();

    // call the public method on it
    temp.third('argument');
}
```

If you are trying to just do a namespace kind of thing, you can do this (no privates as well)

```
// define an object and name it first
var first =
{
    // give first a public variable but make it a function with an arg
    third : function(third_param)
    {
        alert(third_param);
    }

}

function second ()
{
    // call the third method on the first variable
    first.third('argument');
}
```

But probably the best way is via namespacing

```
var first = (function () {
    // define first's private function, store it in 'third', a private variable
    var third = function (third_param) {
        alert(third_param);
    };

    // return this object to the 'first' variable
    return { // define first's public that calls the private
        'callThird': function (call_third_param) {
            third(call_third_param);
        }
    };
} ());  // this line runs the function, closure'ing over the privates and 
// returning an object (that has access to the privates) to the 'first' variable

function second () {
    // usage:
    first.callThird("Hello World!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript won't easily allow it, why would you need to do that in the first place, you might want to use objects or prototypes to accomplish this.

```
function first(){
   third();
}

function second(){

}

function third(){
  second();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make third() a function not nested under first(), and then just have first() and second() call third()?

e.g.

```
function first(){
   third();
}

function second(){
   third();
}

function third(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to pull the function out that is common to both, and just call it where needed.

```
var thirdf = function third () {
}

function first () {
  thirdf();
}

function second () {
  thirdf();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make first return third. This suggestion makes more sense if your example looks more like this:

```
function first(foo) {  // notice that foo is local to first
  function third() {
    // do something with foo in the outer scope
  }
  return third;
}

function second(bar) {
  bar(); // call whatever gets passed in
}

second(first());  // third (created inside first) gets passed to second
```

If you don't have any variables that are local to first (unlike my example, where I used foo), there's no point in not defining third in the global namespace i.e. you should do this instead:

```
function first() {
}

function second() {
  third();
}

function third() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside all the "why would you want to do this?" questions, and assuming you need to do this for a legitimate reason like accessing a "private" function inside some existing code that you don't own, **here's a hack**:

`first.toString()` will give you the entire source of the function. You can inject a bit of code into that function to return you a reference to the third function:

```
var prober = new Function(
    first.toString().replace("{", "{ return third;") + "return first()");
var third = prober();
third(); // yay!
```

But, please **don't do this** if you really don't need to. It's a big hack that I just wanted to mention for educational purposes.